# How do I use my GPG agent for SSH everywhere?

Tags: mojave, ssh, encryption, environment-variables, gpg

On my system, I'm trying to set up SSH authentication through my GPG agent (installed via `brew`). So far, I have this working in my terminal thanks to adding the following lines to `~/.profile`:

```
# Enable SSH support through GPG
export "GPG_TTY=$(tty)"
export "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${HOME}/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"
```

However, GUI applications (e.g. PyCharm) still use the SSH agent built into Mac (annoyingly). Is there any way/place I can use to set my `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` for my entire session? Ideally, I don't want to disable SIP to achieve my goal, and solutions like [this](https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/219042108-Setting-global-environment-variables-on-OS-X) don't seem to work.

For example, running `import os; os.environ['SSH_AUTH_SOCK']` in PyCharm's builtin Python Console will still show `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.whatever/Listeners` instead of my auth sock. Likewise, it will not prompt for my GPG key passcode but instead go through the standard authentication flow.

This also persists in XCode, using a small sample program to get the value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, so it's not PyCharm or a Python-only problem.

I'm currently running Mojave 10.14.4 on my system.

Comment: You're trying to do this? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Set_SSH_AUTH_SOCK

Comment: @slm Effectively, yes, but ideally for my entire user session and not just my terminal.

Comment: OK I'm with ya now.

Comment: you seen this SO Q&A - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-on-os-x?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a single A'er to your Q, rather you'll have to implement several to get everything to pick up this change globally. This A'er shows a "combined" approach that does what you want from what I can tell - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32405815/33204.

Comment: If you want a tool to help w/ this - https://diaryproducts.net/EnvPane

Comment: @slm As for now, I only need to get it working in GUI - the terminal works great. I'll take a look at a few of the links you provided to see if I can piece together a workable solution. Thanks for everything so far!

Comment: @slm Okay, so. I've tried basically every linked solution and Apple's own SSH agent is still taking priority. I'm thinking the builtin Apple agent starts after GPG/user `launchd` and `LaunchAgent`s/EnvPane/etc...  I'll see if I can disable the builtin agent entirely to confirm this suspicion (although that won't really help me resolve the issue)...

Answer (score 6):

So, I managed to find a hacky solution that achieves the same goal. It appears (???) impossible to overwrite `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, and I can't disable the builtin agent because I want to preserve SIP.

However, I can abuse symlinking to get my agent working reliably. Thanks to a [nice article](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/stick-with-security-yubikey-ssh-gnupg-macos) explaining how to leverage the YubiKey on a Mac (similar to my goal), I managed to create a `LaunchAgent` to symlink my agent to wherever `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is pointing. So far I have yet to perform heavy testing with this, but it seems to be working okay.

Just in case the source link goes down, I created a file at `~/Library/LaunchAgents/link-ssh-auth-sock.plist` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>link-ssh-auth-sock</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/bin/sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>/bin/ln -sf $HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh $SSH_AUTH_SOCK</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This LaunchAgent replaces the Apple-generated socket (located in `/private/tmp/...`) with my own, but preserves Apple's environment variable. The symlink works, and is picked up in any application that supports using native SSH (in my case, PyCharm).

It's not a true solution to the issue (the socket is being symlinked, who knows what issues this could cause), but it at least works for the time being.

I'll keep trying to find a *true* solution to this problem, but in the meantime I'll share this answer just for any other curious souls with the same issue.

Comment: Did you managed to find _true_ solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Tampering with symlinks seems to be the best way for now, but it does work pretty well. I've been using this for a while now across multiple machines and have had zero issues.